# How to get query ID after executing psql/mysql CLI command line?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift, psql, singlestore

I am using psql CLI command line to make a query to Redshift. (question applies to mysql also). The query may take a long time to execute. After sending the command, is it  possible to get the Query ID of that query *while* it is running without waiting until it is finished. Is this possible?

For example, if I need to abort that query hours/days later, I'd like to send a CANCEL/ABORT command to the Redshift backend for that specific query. Note: the same database will be used by others, so I'd like to know the ID of the specific query I executed.

Also, let's say the psql command is running in a shell. Is it possible to programmatically (python) in an app to get the Query ID from that psql CLI process?

Comment: `psql` is used with PostGreSQL, not MySQL.

Comment: Thanks. I revised it to apply for both psql and mysql

Comment: can this put you in the direction? http://chrismiles.info/systemsadmin/databases/articles/viewing-current-postgresql-queries/

Comment: Thanks I guess the situation is that there can be many users making queries around the same time. I'd like to be able to uniquely identify the query id or query process id that runs the psql CLI query while it is running on 'this' local machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Amazon Redshift, there are a couple of ways to determine the running queries -

**STV_INFLIGHT** -
 shows only currently running queries (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_INFLIGHT.html)

```
select userid, usename, query, pid, starttime, "text", 
suspended from stv_inflight s, pg_user u 
where s.userid = u.usesysid
```

**STV_RECENTS** -
 shows currently running and recently completed queries with status (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_RECENTS.html)

```
select * from stv_recents;
```

Now, to abort a running query, you need the *pid* (Process ID) of the currently running queries. You can then terminate the query using one of the below commands -

```
select pg_cancel_backend(<pid>); OR
select pg_terminate_backend(<pid>) ; OR
cancel <pid>;
```

query#2

```
select userid, usename, query, s.pid, c.remotehost, c.application_name, 
starttime, "text", 
suspended from stv_inflight s, stl_connection_log c,  pg_user u 
where s.userid = u.usesysid and s.pid = c.pid
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can get the query ID or query process ID of a query that is running by psql command line?

Comment: Thanks I guess the situation is that there can be many users making queries around the same time. I'd like to be able to uniquely identify the query id or query process id that runs the psql CLI query while it is running

Comment: I don't think there is a straight forward way for identifying 'application_name' from connections. Though there is a column called application_name in 'stl_connection_log' table, I haven't seen any value in that column anytime (may be it is just there for internal use). But if you know the IP Address of machines from which psql cli is supposed to run, you can identify sessions from those machines using query#2 (added above now)

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you can run `select connection_id()` to get the connection id of the current connection before running the query. You can then run `kill <id>` from another connection after starting the long running query.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how this can be done for a psql query ran by CLI? It will be useful to cancel a long running psql query

Answer (score 0):

For Redshift, it's `select * from stv_recents where status='Running'` and you'll be able to get `pid` from there

Comment: Thanks I guess the situation is that there can be many users making queries around the same time. I'd like to be able to uniquely identify the query id or query process id that runs the psql CLI query while it is running

Comment: the client info is not showing there I think but you can filter it by userid if you want and if psql is connected under specific user